# How can I connect to a server?

Tags: server, connection, filemanager

I'm new to Ubuntu, so this may actually be quite simple. On windows I can connect to a server in my school's network by typing in "\\servername.edu" and that works fine, but on Ubuntu, I have no idea how to accomplish the same goal. I tried typing that in, but that doesn't work. I've pinged the server to verify that it is up, so that isn't an issue. How can I connect to this server like I can in Windows?

Comment: \servername.edu? or \\servername.edu?

Comment: \\servername.edu I changed it. I typed it right, it just interpreted it as an escape character or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I connect to a Windows share (call it `muru-pc`) on Windows by `\\muru-pc`, I can connect on Ubuntu using:

```
smb://muru-pc
```

So, in the Files (Nautilus) app, you can try connecting to `smb://servername.edu`. To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to get to the address bar, type the address and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I tried that and I got the error message "Unhandled error message: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out"

Answer (score 0):

you will want to start learning about ssh.
1. Download putty.exe
2. enter the ip address of your server into putty and your username, you will be promted for your password.